# Yii Setup Configuration Errors

Tags: php, yii, configuration

I'm new to php frameworks and I am having trouble setting up the Yii framework on my system. In my setup, I followed instructions by using Composer and downloading files to my www/public-vision/server file. 
Apparently, upon running index.php for the first time, I should see something like this:

[image: Normal Login for Yii]

Unfortunately I'm getting a whole bunch of errors (it goes to 20 so far).

[image: Errors]

What's going on and what do I need to do to fix this problem? Obviously, it seems like a configuration problem. If this question isn't specific enough, what do I need to look at to give a more useful question?

Answer (score 1):

Run this command in your shell. www user must be given write permission to assets folder.

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/public-vision/server/basic/web/assets/
```

or

```
chmod -R u+rwx,go+rx,go-w /var/www/public-vision/server/basic/web/assets/
```

Comment: Isn't it pretty dangerous to use a 777 chmod. Shouldn't it be a 755?

Comment: And I ran it and it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: "Don't use 777
Using the permissions of 777 is a very bad idea. It means that anyone can write content to the files. This can lead very easily to arbitrary code getting written to the file and executed every time the script is accessed.

Do a chmod 755 instead. This gives the everyone read and execute permissions, but only the owner write permissions." - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.installation

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. So a couple things: First, I switched over to Yii 1.1. Then, loaded the frameowrk, ran

```
yiic webapp2 [dir]
```

in terminal, and then ran the file. I did encounter the problem that the date wasn't initialized in php.ini. So make sure to add

```
date.timestamp = America/Los_Angeles.
```

Also make sure to change the

```
.htaccess file according to the yii installation. 

RewriteEngine on

# prevent httpd from serving dotfiles (.htaccess, .svn, .git, etc.)
RedirectMatch 403 /\..*$
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

See the guide here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.installation

Finally, you may have potentially problems with php not having curl or json if that is the case type

```
sudo apt-get install php5-json
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you utilise an FTP software (eg. filezilla, etc) you can manually set directories permissions with right click on directory. Try setting 755